# Broadcast receiver in fragment not receiving intent from service

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a broadcast receiver in the onResume method of my fragment. In a service I am trying to send broadcast to this receiver but the intent simply vanishes. It isn't received. I have a broadcat receiver in an activity too which receives broadcasts from this service but there it works fine. Does it have something to do with fragment.

This is the relevant code

In fragment onResume

```
broadcastReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
//                String id="";
                if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("callback_tab")) {
                    if (intent.hasExtra("id") && intent.getStringExtra("id").length() > 0) {
                        //Do work
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter1 = new IntentFilter();
        // set the custom action
        intentFilter.addAction("callback_tab");
        // register the receiver
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver1, intentFilter1);
```

Unregistering is done in onPause() like this

```
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver1);
```

The intent from the service is send as such

```
Intent broadcast1 = new Intent("callback_tab");
broadcast.putExtra("id", id);
sendBroadcast(broadcast1);
```

It would be great if somebody could provide a hint or help. Thanks !!

Comment: basically you should not use broadcasts for service < - > activity interaction, you should use "bound service" pattern

Comment: @pskink , thnx for the reply but sorry I cannot understand why it shouldn't be used? Any link etc would also suffice. Thnx !!

Comment: are you familiar with "bound services" ? do you know how to implement "bound local service" pattern?